# Postman how to use Authorization: Token?

Tags: authorization, postman, token

I have some problem with Postman.

If I use curl via command window - everything works fine:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Token *************************"  http://localhost:8000/me/
```

I have some access to my data.

How to use this token via Postman?

I was trying and I still have error like:

```
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

Have a nice evening!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was using the Authorization or Body Field - That was the problem.

If you want to do it just use Headers Field and:

As Key set "Authorization"

and

As Value "Token *<your_token>*"